# mongoid scope with referenced object as criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, bson

I have following scope for Mongoid model in Rails 3:

```
class Expert
  include Mongoid::Document
  referenced_in :category

   scope :currently_available, lambda { |category, limit|
    limit ||= 5
    {
      :where => {:category => category, :state => 'available'}, 
      :limit => limit
    }
  }
```

`category` here is an instance of referenced model:

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  references_many :experts, :inverse_of => :category
```

When I call the scope as `Expert.currently_available(Category.first, 5)`, I got a Criteria object:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :110 > Expert.currently_available(Category.first, 5)
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {:category=>#<Category _id: 4d95ea8773fdea4c47000003, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4d95ea8773fdea4c47000003'), title: "Tax Advisors", price: 5.5>, :state=>"available"},
  options:  {:limit=>5},
  class:    Expert,
  embedded: false>
```

**Question is:** How can I load a collection within this criteria? When I do `.to_a`, it says:
`Cannot serialize an object of class Category into BSON`

Category itself is valid BSON obj when picked up directly, but in scope it fails to render referencing obj.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `:where => {:category => category._id, :state => 'available'},` seems working. Can anybody confirm/correct me please?

Comment: Still cannot get it to work unfortunately. Tried different mongo operatorrs with matching by category._id - it simply returns empty array.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me(Mongoid 2.0):

```
:where => {:category_id => category.id, :state => 'available'}
```

Comment: .id is alias for ._id. `ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > e.id  
 => BSON::ObjectId('4d9b5c6173fdeab5e6000008')  
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003 > e._id  
 => BSON::ObjectId('4d9b5c6173fdeab5e6000008')  `

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but the key here was to use "category_id" instead of "category"