# BSON::InvalidDocument: Cannot serialize an object of class User into BSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have these relationships:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :orders, :class_name => 'Order', :inverse_of => :user
  has_many :sold_orders, :class_name => 'Order', :inverse_of => :seller
end

class Order
 include Mongoid::Document
 belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :orders
 belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :sold_orders
end
```

If I want get all orders for current seller I run in my controller something like:

```
def jobs
  @orders = Order.where(seller: current_user)
  p @orders
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => 'centered'}
    end
end
```

I can see in my log console:

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {:seller=>#<User _id: 500541f81d41c82f1b000037, _type: "User", created_at: 2012-07-17 10:44:08 UTC, ....more attributes>},
  options:  {},
  class:    Order,
  embedded: false>
```

This is wrong because I get a user, but I want get all orders for current seller.

How can I get all orders for current seller?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523582/mongoid-scope-with-referenced-object-as-criteria/5556041#5556041

Comment: I'm using mongoid 2.4.12. It does not works for me :(. With `@orders = Order.where(:seller_id => current_user.id)` Thank you very much!

Comment: So, where is this exception raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally fine. What you see in console is a Mongoid::Criteria object. Mongoid is very lazy to hit the database and does it only when it absolutely needs to. So instead of accessing the databse here

```
    @orders = Order.where(seller: current_user)
```

it only keeps the proxy object and will load the orders when you try to do something on that data. So in order to get your orders in console you may do this:

```
    p @orders.to_a
```

Moreover, Mongoid does not support `.where(seller: current_user)`. You need to create your query based on ids for relations so you should build your query like this:

```
    @orders = Order.where(seller_id: current_user.id)
```

Another thing is - you have relations defined so I would use them instead of creating the query yourself so instead of

```
    @orders = Order.where(seller_id: current_user.id)
```

you can use

```
    @orders = current_user.solo_orders
```

and you don't have to worry if you need to use `seller` or `seller_id`

Comment: Thank you now it does works fine with `@orders.to_a` to array. Thank you